# Retrofit 2 error - End of input at line 1 column 1 path $

Tags: retrofit2, rx-java2

Im using Retrofit 2 with RxJava -

```
@retrofit2.http.Multipart
@retrofit2.http.POST(APIEndPoint.BATCHES)
fun submitGenericMultiPart(@retrofit2.http.Part("data") batchRequests: RequestBody, @retrofit2.http.Part("identifier") multipartTypedOutput: MultipartBody): Single<Array<BatchRequestResponse>>

mDataManager.submitGenericMultiPart(body, files)
                ?.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                ?.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                ?.subscribe(object : SingleObserver<Array<BatchRequestResponse>> {
                    override fun onSubscribe(d: Disposable) {
                        if(d!=null) compositeDisposable.add(d)
                    }

                    override fun onSuccess(it: Array<BatchRequestResponse>) {
                        // success block
                    }

                    override fun onError(e: Throwable) {
                        // error block
                    }
                })
```

Is there any error in the way I have declared the data types handling it in RxJava because every time, I get the error - End of input at line 1 column 1 path $

Answer (score 1):

Cause: data response is empty, you can add NullOnEmptyConverterFactory to handle when the data response is empty.

Issue: https://github.com/square/retrofit/issues/1968

Solution: https://github.com/square/retrofit/issues/1554

Comment: no. data response is not empty. It is of type Array<BatchRequestResponse>

Comment: Can you share json response?

Comment: the status code of the response is 403 with a custom message - {"statusCode":403,"message":"validate properly"}  ... How to handle these ?